# $X^TXw$ is normal?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

I'm reading a paper in which it claims that if the matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has elements which are normal and independent, then for an arbitrary vector $w$, $X^TXw$ is distributed as $\sqrt{n}||w||N(0,I_n)$. Is it true? Because multiplying a normal to itself does not produce a normal. (http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6796-learning-relus-via-gradient-descent.pdf, page 7, equation 6.3)

Comment: This doesn't sound right. When $w=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$, the first entry of $X^TXw$ is Chi-squared, not normal.

Comment: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6796-learning-relus-via-gradient-descent.pdf, Page 7, equation 6.3: $(w^*)^TX^TX$ is replaced with $a^T$, which is Gaussian.